# MPU6050 Quaternion calculation with stm32

Tags: stm32, quaternions, gyroscope, mpu6050

I've been interested in mpu6050 for a while. I can read gyro data but i need help how to convert it to quaternion. This is pretty easy on Arduino, jrowberg's library is really great. But i am working with a STM32F4.

I also checked the mpu6050's datasheet. I was able to compile such a code for calculations.

definations like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float Temperature;

    int16_t Gyro_X_RAW;
    int16_t Gyro_Y_RAW;
    int16_t Gyro_Z_RAW;
    float Gx;
    float Gy;
    float Gz;
} MPU6050_t;

typedef struct {
    float w;
    float x; 
    float y; 
    float z; 
} Quaternion;

Quaternion q = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; 
MPU6050_t MPU6050;
```

code i found to read gyro data:

```
void MPU6050_Read_Gyro(I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2Cx, MPU6050_t *DataStruct)
{
    uint8_t Rec_Data[6];

    // Read 6 BYTES of data starting from GYRO_XOUT_H register

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, GYRO_XOUT_H_REG, 1, Rec_Data, 6, 100);

    DataStruct->Gyro_X_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[0] << 8 | Rec_Data[1]);
    DataStruct->Gyro_Y_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[2] << 8 | Rec_Data[3]);
    DataStruct->Gyro_Z_RAW = (int16_t)(Rec_Data[4] << 8 | Rec_Data[5]);

    /*** convert the RAW values into dps (�/s)
         we have to divide according to the Full scale value set in FS_SEL
         I have configured FS_SEL = 0. So I am dividing by 131.0
         for more details check GYRO_CONFIG Register              ****/

    DataStruct->Gx = DataStruct->Gyro_X_RAW / 131.0;
    DataStruct->Gy = DataStruct->Gyro_Y_RAW / 131.0;
    DataStruct->Gz = DataStruct->Gyro_Z_RAW / 131.0;

}
```

Infinite loop:

```
while (1)
  {
      MPU6050_Read_Temp(&hi2c1, &MPU6050);
      MPU6050_Read_Gyro(&hi2c1, &MPU6050);
      float gyroX = MPU6050.Gx;
      float gyroY = MPU6050.Gy;
      float gyroZ = MPU6050.Gz;
      calculateQuaternion(&q, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ, dt);

      char buffer[50];    
      uint8_t size = sprintf(buffer,"quat\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\r\n", q.w, q.x, q.y, q.z);      
      HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)buffer, size, 1000);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
```

calculateQuaternion:

```
void calculateQuaternion(Quaternion *q, float gyroX, float gyroY, float gyroZ, float dt) {

    float dThetaX = gyroX * dt;
    float dThetaY = gyroY * dt;
    float dThetaZ = gyroZ * dt;

    float dq0 = 1.0;
    float dq1 = dThetaX * 0.5;
    float dq2 = dThetaY * 0.5;
    float dq3 = dThetaZ * 0.5;

    q->w += dq0 * q->w - dq1 * q->x - dq2 * q->y - dq3 * q->z;
    q->x += dq0 * q->x + dq1 * q->w + dq2 * q->z - dq3 * q->y;
    q->y += dq0 * q->y - dq1 * q->z + dq2 * q->w + dq3 * q->x;
    q->z += dq0 * q->z + dq1 * q->y - dq2 * q->x + dq3 * q->w;

    float norm = sqrt(q->w * q->w + q->x * q->x + q->y * q->y + q->z * q->z);
    q->w /= norm;
    q->x /= norm;
    q->y /= norm;
    q->z /= norm;
}
```

But when I check in debug mode, there is not much change in the gyro data, even when the sensor is fixed, the quaternion data continues to change.

[serial port output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jywd3.jpg)

Can you help me correct if I am doing a mistake in the calculation? I would appreciate it if you could suggest a library or example that I can use.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're doing? I take it raw data from the sensor is correct, so there was no need to post the code that reads the data (confirm?). Your question is mainly about math algorithm? What exactly is the input and the output of what you're trying to do? "the quaternion data continues to change" - what does that mean? The function gives different outputs for the same input? Did you verify all input parameters are the same while output is different? There is nothing sus in calculateQuaternion() that could look like undefined behavior (but check if norm is 0).

Comment: Your code in `calculateQuaternion()` is constantly adding things to `q->x` etc. Of course it will change each time you call it. I don't know if you should be assigning to `q->x` etc or adding to them.

Comment: I want to read the quaternion data from the sensor and print it to the serial port with the uart. "https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino" I couldn't find dmpGetQuaternion function like here for STM32. So I looked at the sensor's datasheet and examples. My sampling time is 1 second. i.e. I don't think the constant changing of data is related to assignments. I thought the data might be wrong because my quaternion data is constantly changing. so I started to read other data, but I couldn't see any problem in the data.

Comment: I can explain the change as follows. I fix my sensor and start reading the data. However, even though the sensor is stationary, data is coming as if it is rotating. I added the serial port output to my question for easier understanding. There is no big difference between the values. However, the value range is 1 to -1 (norm). Even a 0.1 change makes difference.